# What does this datetime mean?

Tags: datetime-format

Could someone tell me what this datetime means?

```
2014-10-12T21:48:42-04:00
```

1. Why is there a `T` in the middle?
2. Why is there a `-04:00` at the end? Does it represent the time between 2014-10-12T21:48:42 and 4 hours before that time (or 4 minutes)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a timestamp in ISO 8601 format:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

> Why is there a "T" in the middle?

That is the symbol separating the date from the time.

> why is there a -04:00 at the end? Does it represent the time between
>   2014-10-12T21:48:42 and 4 hours before that time (or 4 minutes)?

That indicates the time zone offset from UTC

Answer (score 0):

This is the ISO 8601 format used by the [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime).

That date time means October 12, 2014 at 21:48:42 at a timezone -4 hours from UTC.